# What distribution would describe this?

Tags: statistics

I start with 100 eggs, 10 of them being broken. I randomly select eggs without replacement until they are all split into baskets of 10 eggs each.

Here's what I know:

- Best case scenario all 10 bad eggs go into 1 basket, giving me 9 good baskets out of 10. Worst case is each basket carries 1 bad egg giving me 0 good baskets.
- Probability of any one basket being good, p, is 0.90^10=0.349.
- Mean number of good baskets would be 10*0.349=3.49? However this calculation assumes replacements, or at least requires large number of baskets/eggs to be a good approximation. Every good basket created decreases the probability that the next basket(s) will be good.

For large numbers of eggs, say 50,000, is the non-replacement a big issue?
Which distribution would allow me to calculate a confidence interval for the mean number of good baskets? Given that there are a large number of eggs (thousands), with known defect rate (around 1%) and fixed number of eggs per basket.

Comment: For a large numbers of eggs, the form of a reasonable approximation depends on whether you have a large number of baskets or a small number of baskets.

Comment: I might be wrong but in my intuition asking for the probability that a basket is full of good eggs is like asking for the prob. of hitting 0 winning tickets in a lottery with a total of 100 tickets and 10 winning tickets, i.e. a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @GenericNickname: Indeed the probability of any one basket being good is ${90 \choose 10}/{100 \choose 10}\approx 0.33$ so the expected number of good baskets is about $3.3$

Comment: @Henry Can one really compute the expected number of good baskets like this? I mean the prob of two baskets being good is not just $0.33 \cdot 0.33$ since the events are not independent.

Comment: @GenericNickname: Yes, but linearity of expectation holds for dependent random variables too. Henry is computing the expectation of the sum of random variables $X_i = \{\text{$1$ if basket $i$ is good, $0$ otherwise}\}$.

Comment: @Rahul Right, I always seem to forget about the easiest solutions :) Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: {90 \choose 10}/{100 \choose 10}\approx 0.33 makes sense to me. Is it possible to get a confidence interval around this mean?